# На какое слово падает ударение в предложении?

Tags: орфоэпия, тактовое-ударение, логическое-ударение

Предложение такое: "Купи лук, картошку, капусту".

Answer (score 3):

Вы вроде бы ответили мне, что не меня имели в виду, когда спрашивали о тактовом, логическом и, кажется, других ударениях.
О каком ударении идёт речь здесь? Если о логическом, то в таком предложении сложно его вычленить. Простая, обычная перечислительная интонация с выделением каждого нужного для покупки продукта: *Купи л**у**к, карт**о**шку, кап**у**сту.*

Если предположить, что у того, которого посылают за покупкой, есть проблемы с памятью, то в речи посылающего вполне может присутствовать именно подчёркнутое ударение на одном слове. Например, посылаемый забыл купить капусту. Тогда лучше ещё добавить союз ***и***:
*Я что тебе сказала? Купи лук, картошку и кап**УУУУ**стууу.*

А может быть и на всех:
*Я же сказала тебе купить л**УУУ**к, карт**ООО**шку, кап**УУУ**сту. А ты что принёс?!! Чесн**О**к, мор**О**женое... и арб**УУУУУ**з?!! Идиот...* (На арбузе особенное, **сверхлогическое**, ударение.)

Короче, вариантов может быть множество. Логическое ударение, как Вы правильно отметили, делается на самом важном для сообщения слове.

Comment: Я имею ввиду не логическое, а то самое, которое вы называете ударением. Вы говорили, что теперь просто пишете ‟ударение”. Про логическое ударение и так понятно, что оно есть только тогда, когда его кто-то делает, не нужно про него писать. Я не отмечал, что оно делается на самом важном слове, я отмечал, что оно делается только тогда, когда есть специфическая причина выделить некое слово и когда это слово выделяется более громким произношение и затянутой ударной гласной, что его нет в большинстве предложений.

Comment: Не существует самого важного слова в предложении, все слова в предложении одинаково важны.

Comment: Вот же ваша цитата: ‟С ним, по-моему, всё понятно – так, как вы написали в начале вопроса. И этот термин я уже не употребляю, пишу просто "ударение". Я спрашиваю про это ударение, а не про логическое ударение. В том вопросе я не имел ввиду вас, а в этом вопросе я обращаюсь к вам. Могу удалить это, раз уж вы ответили уже.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin  Да, в самом простом варианте здесь нет логического ударения. Скорее всего, имеет место тактовое ударение: *Купи л**у**к, [купи] карт**о**шку, [купи] кап**у**сту*.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin  " Не существует самого важного слова в предложении, все слова в предложении одинаково важны".  С этим не могу согласиться. Как раз логическое ударение и показывает это главное слово для донесения нужной информации. // Всё, я спать.

Comment: Но в большинстве предложений его нет, логическое ударение – астрономически редкое явление в речи.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin  Про астрономию вы уже говорили, помню. Как можно эту редкость вычислить? Ну да ладно – это меня не слишком волнует. Есть фразовое ударение, которое при обычной, спокойной речи падает на последнее слово каждой фразы. Но в вашем примере с картошками такого нет, потому что каждая картошка важна.

Comment: Возьмите любую речь, и там, скорее всего, не будет ни одного логического ударения. Это очевидно, что оно очень редкое. Так на какие слова или слово здесь падет ударение? Какой ответ в итоге?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Я же ответил: "Простая перечислительная интонация". Каждый продукт выделяется своим собственным словесным ударением. Никаких особых ударений нет. // Извините,  на сегодня больше не могу уделять внимание русскому языку

Comment: То есть нет никакого ударения (я не про ударения в словах, понятно, что ударения в словах есть всегда)? В предложении нет этого самого ударения? Давайте называть его тактовое ударение. Нет вообще ни одного тактового ударения?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin  Хорошо. Ударение падает на капусту, так как она стоит в самом конце предложения. Это основной принцип построения фразы. Но оно минимальное, так как есть другие члены, имеющие такое же значение для донесения просьбы, приказа.

Comment: А как это определить, по каким признакам? Все однородные произносятся с одинаковой интонацией. А почему не на все три однородных? А как вообще узнать, что оно там есть.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin Вы слишком заморочились, по-моему. Вот ваши предложения. *"А к**А**к это определить, по как**И**м признакам? Все однородные произносятся с один**А**ковой интонацией. А почему не на вс**Е** три однородных? А как вообще узн**А**ть, что оно там **Е**сть"*. Или:  *"А как это определ**И**ть, по каким пр**И**знакам?"*  // До встречи!

Comment: А почему это в предложении: ‟Все однородные произносятся с один**А**ковой интонацией” – такое ударение, как это определить?

Comment: А расставьте в следующем предложении: ‟Мы идем в школу, где нам предстоит получить новые знания и встретить старых друзей”.

Comment: Очень интересное объяснение у Александра,  мне нравится. Добавлю немного информации об однородных членах. Вообще говоря, тоническое ударение падает на все однородные члены, но для первых двух это повышение тона, а для последнего — понижение тона в конце предложения. Поэтому оно будет логически ВЫДЕЛЕННЫМ, то есть неоднородным по отношению к первым двум.

Comment: Я знаю чьи речи можно взять в качестве пособия по логическим ударениям. В речах Путина сплошные логические ударения. Вот этим умением он овладел с мастерством.